# I send http post request with angular but it does not go to the asp.net mvc action and returns html layout tags

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an angular application with asp.net mvc and i made a registration form with identity, I have layout and index mvc view which i just write in it ng-view tag  and i inject html pages in it, I am doing a http post request from angular controller to mvc action method but the request does not go to the mvc action, whereas when i change th views to mvc views and make a templateUrl in angular map to mvc method it works well.
Can any one help me in this problem.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<JsonResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        string message = "";
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                MiddleName = model.MiddleName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                UserStatus = UserStatus.Waiting
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                message = "Success";
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
                message = "InvalidEmail";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Failed!";
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

and this is my angular controller

```
MyApp.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope','$http',function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.message = '';
$scope.isFormValid = false;
//Check Form Validation
$scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function (newValue) {
    $scope.isFormValid = newValue;
});
//Save Data
$scope.SaveData = function (data) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.message = '';
    if ($scope.isFormValid) {


        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Account/Register',
            data: data
        }).then(function (response) {

            // check your response (if a success status code was resolved)
            console.log(response.data);

        }, function (error) {

            // check your error response
            console.log(error);

        });

    } else {

         $scope.message = "Please Fill the blanks";

    }
}
```

}]);

and this is my html page:

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterController">
<form name="f1" ng-submit="SaveData(user)" novalidate>
   controls here
</form
```

Comment: No offence meant, but how can someone help without showing any piece of code? You gotta post the controller action as well as the client side code so that others could identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for update; I was going through the comments in thr below answer and it seems like tge request is hitting the action but `RegisterViewModel model)` model is null or values are empty, is that right?

Comment: No values in not empty

Comment: If values are not empty then what is the issue?

Comment: the http request does not go to mvc method !

Answer (score 1):

1) Check your browser console for any javascript errors, if you have any, resolve them and try again!

2) Check you have the correct [ActionMethodSelectorAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)  attribute ([`[HttpPost]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)) over your controller method and that your method name is spelt correctly.

3) Check that you have the correct path in your request.

4) Check you are sending the correct data to the controller!!!

5) Check that the method is public.

6) Check that you are authorised to access that controller/method.

7) Check that you don't have any duplicate method names with either, a) the same parameters and name (if your not using an [ActionMethodSelectorAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx), or b) the same names and method select attributes.

8) Remove all parameters from your method, put a breakpoint at the start of the method, and try making the request and see if it hits the breakpoint. If it works without parameters and not with, then you are not passing the correct required data into the method.

9) Make your request and check the response!! (example below):

```
// make your request
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Controller/Method',
    data: {
        foo: bar
    }
}).then(function(response) {

    // check your response (if a success status code was resolved)
    console.log(response);

}, function(error) {

    // check your error response
    console.log(error);

});
```

If you have a 404 then your method was not found, if you have a 500 then something blew up in your code, if you have a 401 then you are unauthorised etc... This is really useful to actually know what is going on with your request...

10) Check your application is running!

Comment: yes i have [HttpPost] attribute over my controller method

Comment: This is my mvc action method:
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous] 
    public async Task<JsonResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {

    }
}
and this is my angular http request in controller,
$http.post("/Account/Register", data).then(function (d) {
                alert("success");
            }, function (d) {
                alert('error');
            });

Comment: `console.log` the values of `d` in both the success and error parts of your http request, what status code does it give you?

Comment: If you are not hitting a breakpoint in your register method, then the issue you have is with your data being passed into your register method. console.log(data) before you call your `$http.post` request and check you have everything you need and the key, value pairs are correct

Comment: the status code 200 but it does not go to the mvc method

Comment: I hit a breakpoint in my mvc method but the request never go to it

Comment: Ok if you hit a breakpoint in your method then the request HAS got to it, maybe you mean your data did not?, can you show ALL of your register code?

Comment: No the request never got the break point and the returned data is HTML tags

Comment: Ok, what is the html page that it is returning?

Comment: I want to inform you that it works when i change my view from html page to mvc view but i don not know why

Comment: Please show your AngularJS request code and your C# Account Controller code in your question at the top in snippets.